# Browser extension to replace website JS with own JS

Tags: browser, browser-addons, javascript

Is there a browser extension that can run a local JS file instead of the linked file from the website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify which browser, but the concept of [GreaseMonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey), which is available in FireFox, is also available in some other browsers too.

Basically you can hook into the browser page load, and load your own javascript which could in theory rewrite some of the DOM including it's javascript...

Comment: Thank you =) With google chrome you even don't need an extension, chrome just accepts the greasemonkey scripts =)

Comment: Very nice;  I knew chrome was working on supporting greasemonkey scripts a year or so ago.  Good to hear it's in now.

Answer (score 1):

not only Greasemonkey, but also Chickenfoot, Platypus, Selenium, .., iMacros would do the job. Or you can insert .js with Proxomitron/Privoxy/any other proxy.